# react-spring - animate <p> elements on content change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

The following code is a simple react component that uses **react-spring** to animate the `p` (`animated.p`) elements. The animation is defined in the `fadeIn`constant and is assigned to the `animated.p` elements via the `style={fadeIn}` tags.

```js
//returns and animates <p> elements:
function QuoteBox(props) {
  const fadeIn = useSpring({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 } });
  return (
    <>
    <blockquote>
      <animated.p id="text" style={fadeIn}>{props.quote}</animated.p>
    </blockquote>
    <animated.p id="author" style={fadeIn}>{props.author}<cite><em>{props.from}</em></cite></animated.p>
    </>
  );
}
```

When the page loads and the `QuoteBox`component is mounted into the DOM, `useSpring` changes the opacity of the `animated.p` elements from 0 to 1.
However, I need this to happen every time I pass new `props` to the `animated.p` elements, but I'm struggling to understand how to do that.

There are some [simple examples](https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-spring) on the react-spring docs page, which uses the `state` (`toggle`) of the component to change the opacity from 0 to 1 and visa-versa, but it's not clear to me how to change the opacity from 0 to 1 **every time** I pass a new `prop` to the `animated.p` elements.
I'm just trying to obtain a simmple text fade-in when it changes.

Sorry for the previous confused question, this may be a little too difficult for me. Also, I'm not entirely sure react-spring is a good choice, it seems overly complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Question is not clear. Post more code and explain what you want to do a bit more please?

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the updater function syntax. It is initialised with a function which returns the initial properties, and returns an updater function (as well as a `stop` function, not used here) which allows the initial properties to be overwritten:

```
function QuoteBox(props) {
  const [fadeIn, set] = useSpring(() => ({ opacity: 0 }));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    set({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 }});
  }, [set, props.quote, props.author, props.from]);

  return (
    <>
      <blockquote>
        <animated.p id="text" style={fadeIn}>
          {props.quote}
        </animated.p>
      </blockquote>
      <animated.p id="author" style={fadeIn}>
        {props.author}
        <cite>
          <em>{props.from}</em>
        </cite>
      </animated.p>
    </>
  );
```

This will effectively reset the animation on mount and for every subsequent rerender where the props change. React (or ESlint) will probably complain about the above use of `useEffect` since none of the prop values are actually getting used, we're just watching them for changes since it seems implied that that's when the animation should rerun.

You could potentially avoid this with:

**Memoisation:**

```
const MemoQuoteBox = React.memo(QuoteBox);
```

Since all the props are strings (a simple data type which is equal by value, not by reference like objects or arrays) you can memoise the component as it is and it will only rerender when one of them changes. This will allow you to remove the dependency array since now the component is only going to update when a prop changes:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  set({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 }});
});
```

If you're going to pass more props to this component in the future it might not be ideal.

**Reference:**

```
const currString = props.quote + props.author + props.from;
const prevString = React.useRef(currString);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (currString === prevString.current) return;
  set({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 }});
  prevString.current = currString;
}, [set, currString]);
```

Now that we're using the passed value ESlint shouldn't throw up a warning. I've taken advantage of the fact the props are all strings to concat them here (since they are conceptually linked) but the principle would be the same if you kept them separate.

**Dirty Return:**

Just return the values directly from the effect and ESlint should consider them "used" although at this point you might as well just use `eslint-disable-next-line`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  set({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0 }});
  return props.quote + props.author + props.from;
}, [set, props.quote, props.author, props.from]);
```

Comment: You're right, React complains about useState and useEffect not being used, but it works. I'll need to have a better look at your code and explanation. Thanks

Comment: @marco1618 I edited some examples of how you'd get rid of the warning since you mentioned it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Very exhaustive explanation, thank you! That has been helpful.